# How to release resources?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android.Now am  developing a game in android where i need to release all the resources on a button click as the game comes to an end..How to do that?

Comment: Please be more specific, what type of resources are you talking about?

Comment: Resources like media player,camera etc...

Comment: You should look into documentation of each resource type you want to release, usually every class that uses some kind of resources has a method for releasing those resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device has it's own release methods. In general terms, look for the release() method of the device object you are using.
For the resources you asked, you can take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release%28%29) for the camera, and the following [example](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/) for the Media Player.